# Why ASP.NET MVC 2 is rendering this code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, editorformodel

I have an bool property in a class. And using `<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>` its generating this code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <input class="check-box" id="Ativo" name="Ativo" type="checkbox" value="true">
  <input name="Ativo" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

**My question is: why it's creating an input hidden ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you submit a form, unless the checkbox is checked, it will not be submitted to the server in the postback. it helps distinguish between a false value and a missing value. They are just working around one of the vagaries of the way forms work on the web.

Comment: So an input type=checkbox has a priority over an input type=hidden when they both have the same name or is it because the checkbox is first in the DOM?

Comment: It's because they have the same name and the first one takes priority.